# C# CodeProvider: Class inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, scripting

So I've set up a little scripting engine for a game I'm making, using CodeProvider.
I've got some custom classes that I've defined in my project that the scripts need access to, but, even once I've added the Assembly Reference ("NAMEOFEXE.exe") class inheritance doesn't seem to work right.

I can *inherit* the class, but I cannot change fields or anything. EG.

Code inside project:

```
public class inheritable {
   internal string _name = "NoName";
}
```

Code inside script:

```
public class MyClass : inheritable {
   public MyClass() {
      _name = "Custom class in script";
   }
}
```

On script comilation, I get:

```
error CS1061: 'inheritable' does not contain a definition for '_name' and no extension method '_name' accepting a first argument of type 'inheritable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What are the namespaces for `inheritable` and `MyClass`? Do you have a `using name_of_inheritable's_namespace;` at the top of your `MyClass` file?

Comment: Do you need to make inheritable public?

Comment: They are both 'ScriptProj'. And no, I don't. I shall try that.

Comment: Adding 'using ScriptProj;' to the top of the file does not change anything.

Comment: are they in the same assembly? internal only applies to the assembly. make it protected internal if you want it inheritable and settable throughout asswmbly

Comment: Thanks. I've used this in conjunction with the answer I chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class inheritable {
   protected internal string _name = "NoName";
}
```

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer, as it is what I am now using.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're using `internal` vs. `protected` or `protected internal`?

If you need public read access and protected set access, then simply use an automatic property:

```
public string _name { get; protected set; }
```

You could also define a constructor in `inheritable` that takes in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Define a getter and setter on _name:-

```
public string _name{
    get; set;
}
```

Comment: That's all well and good, but I would like this property to be fully editable by the owner class only, and read only elsewhere, hence the internal :/

Comment: @Ruirize You can use public get, private set you know that?

Comment: Then you cannot access the value from outside the class. I still need to be able to read it.

Comment: If the getter is public and the setter is private, the inheritable class will be able to set the property, and everything else will be able to get the property only. `public string _name{get; private set;}`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, looks like you should be making _name protected, since you want derived classes to have access to it. I would recommend changing it from a field, to a property.

Comment: Well, currently my setup denotes the _name field as internal protected, and then I use a more readable read-only property to allow access to it.

Comment: Why also 'internal'? Do you expect that other types in the assembly, not derived from your base class, will need access to it?